# What is the best way to explain bit manipulation to the students?

Tags: assembly, embedded, bit-manipulation

I am currently planning to conduct a Training Workshop on Optimized C Code for Microcontroller Applications.

Currently I am stuck on how to explain bit manipulation in C?

Exactly what I don't want is to lead students to bit structure but guide them to use bit manipulation efficiently...

Any advice?

Comment: "Exactly what I don't want is to lead students to bit structure" I don't get this - how could you possibly understand bit manipulation if you don't understand the structure?

Comment: @annakata - I could be wrong, but I think what he means is that he doesn't want to start off with 'bit-fields' in struct declarations. In my opinion, it would be good if he never talks about them.

Comment: agreed, bitfields in structs are VERY bad and should never be used much less talked about

Comment: Precisely why he will need to talk about bit fields. And provide very simple explanation of why they are VERY bad.  Otherwise they will read about them in books and think great, easy way to do bit manipulation.

Comment: @dwelch: Why are bitfields in structs very bad? Or do you really mean mapping structs over byte arrays (via pointer casting or union) to parse the byte data, which is bad for a number of reasons?

Answer (score 14):

Don't start off with the C statements and syntax. Start them with basic Boolean algebra, and then have them do a bunch of binary arithmetic by hand. Once they actually understand the math behind AND, XOR, NAND, etc, the programming syntax will be immediately understandable in any language. More importantly, they will be entirely familiar with useful transformations like de Morgan's laws, and other properties of bitwise algebra like transitivity that can be used to collapse long ops into shorter ones.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should focus on what actual tasks are solved with bit manipulation so that they understand *why*. Bit manipulation itself is quite simple but can be overwhelming if a person doesn't understand why they are exposed to it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

1. Truth tables of AND, OR, and XOR
2. Binary representation of decimal and hex numbers
3. Apply AND, OR, and XOR to binary numbers.
4. Set a bit without modifying other bits
5. Clear a bit without modifying other bits
6. Toggle a bit without modifying other bits

Answer (score 2):

Start with the basics and work up.

**Basic Boolean Algebra**

Practice Boolean Algebra with Truth Tables. Write column of all inputs and break down the steps to calculate.

[Binary Logical Connectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_operator#All_binary_logical_connectives)

**Not**

```
A | Not A
--+-------
0 |   1
1 |   0
```

**And**

```
A | B | A And B
--+---+--------
0 | 0 |    0 
0 | 1 |    0
1 | 0 |    0
1 | 1 |    1
```

**Or**

```
A | B | A Or B
--+---+-------
0 | 0 |    0 
0 | 1 |    1
1 | 0 |    1
1 | 1 |    1
```

**Xor**

```
A | B | A Xor B
--+---+--------
0 | 0 |    0 
0 | 1 |    1
1 | 0 |    1
1 | 1 |    0
```

An Exercise:

```
(A And B) Or (B And C)

A | B | C | A And B | B And C | (A And B) Or (B And C)
--+---+---+---------+---------+-----------------------
0 | 0 | 0 |    0    |    0    |           0    
0 | 0 | 1 |    0    |    0    |           0    
0 | 1 | 0 |    0    |    0    |           0    
0 | 1 | 1 |    0    |    1    |           1    
1 | 0 | 0 |    0    |    0    |           0    
1 | 0 | 1 |    0    |    0    |           0    
1 | 1 | 0 |    1    |    0    |           1        
1 | 1 | 1 |    1    |    1    |           1
```

**Binary Representations**

Hexadecimal Representation

```
Hex | Binary
----+-------
0   |  0000
1   |  0001
2   |  0010
3   |  0011
4   |  0100
5   |  0101
6   |  0110
7   |  0111
8   |  1000
9   |  1001
A   |  1010
B   |  1011
C   |  1100
D   |  1101
E   |  1110
F   |  1111

So,
1A6 = 0001 1010 0110
```

**Logical Statement Reduction**

[Properties of Boolean Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_operator#All_binary_logical_connectives)

[De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

```
Not (A Or B) = (Not A) And (Not B)
Not (A And B) = (Not A) Or (Not B)
```

**Examples of and code for Bit Manipulation Uses**

There is a very good article on many uses for Bit Manipulation Uses called [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) by Sean Eron Anderson.

Answer (score 1):

guide them by giving them examples of different logic gates and laws, you can also give couple of examples of designing logical circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start with an inefficiently implemented, but useful, solution.

And then show how an efficient implmentation is done.